# What are the softwares prerequisite to run SQL Server on machine?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am working on a project which is in on client server architecture (Network), I want to place my SQL Server 2008 Express database on a centralised server, and my .net windows application should be able to access them at client machines.

What are the minimum software requirements needed on that server to run SQL Server database such that multiple client applications are able to connect simultaneously?

Comment: Certainly you could found the details by Googling, anyway have read of [Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2008 R2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms143506(v=sql.105).aspx) MSDN article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Server installer itself checks for all the prerequisites. If prerequisite is not there, it will automatically install them or give you link to download them.

Comment: actully i am looking if its possible without any installation? and access them over network path, just as we do in case from datadirectory

Comment: No that is not possible. You have to install to use it.